# Passing returned command value to another function

Tags: macros, formatting, parameters, date

I'm trying to pass a value of a command to another function without luck. For example I've some data in `\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{definitions}{\data.def}` to which I access with `\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}{value}`.

Now I want to pass this value from `data.def` (e.g 1990-10-09) to `\printdate{}` so I can format this date into my language preferred format: *October 9, 1990*.

I thought I could easily pass my returned value which is stored in `\DTLfetch{}` to `\printdate{}` without success: `\printdate{\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}{value}}` will throw an error like: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iso@date.` but calling `\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}` alone will print the unformatted (raw) date value without any problem.

Unfortunately I could not find any help resources concerning passing function values into another function. I would be happy if anybody could provide me some addition information about this topic. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Answer (score 3):

A minimal (non) working example exhibiting what packages/documentclass you use and in which ways macros are called is missing.

I assume `\DTLfetch` comes from the **datatool** package and `\printdate` comes from the **isodate** package.

---

On the one hand the command `\DTLfetch` itself is not a command which is fully expandable. That means that (temporary) assignments and the like get carried out whenever that command is called.

On the other hand `\printdate` expects its argument to contain only tokens that

- either are fully expandable and whose expansion at some stage yields only tokens belonging to the character sequence forming the date
- or belong to the character sequence forming the date.

But the command `\DTLfetch` does not just print/return a value, it also saves that value to the macro `\dtlcurrentvalue`.
`\dtlcurrentvalue` in turn is fully expandable.

Therefore right after calling `\DTLfetch` you can use the macro `\dtlcurrentvalue` within the argument of `\printdate`.

As just said, `\DTLfetch` does also print the returned value.

If you don't wish the value to be printed, don't use the command `\DTLfetch` but use the command `\DTLgetvalueforkey` instead which—within another argument—lets you specify the name of a macro which is to be (re)defined to expand to the desired return-value.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[num]{isodate}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{MyDataFile.def}
WhatsoeverKeyA,WhatsoeverValueA
WhatsoeverKeyB,WhatsoeverValueB
MyFromDate,1990-10-09
WhatsoeverKeyC,WhatsoeverValueC
\end{filecontents*}


\newcommand\data{MyDataFile}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{definitions}{\data.def}

\begin{document}

This does both print the return-value and save the return-value to
\verb|\dtlcurrentvalue|:

\verb|\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}{value}|:
\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}{value}\\
\begingroup\footnotesize
\verb|% use the database "definitions".|\\
\verb|% use the column whose name is "value".|\\
\verb|% use the row which in the column "key" holds the item "MyFromData".|
\endgroup

\verb|\dtlcurrentvalue| yields: \dtlcurrentvalue

Now you can use \verb|\dtlcurrentvalue| within the argument of 
\verb|\printdate|.

\verb|\printdate{\dtlcurrentvalue}| yields: \printdate{\dtlcurrentvalue}

\hrulefill

This does just save the return-value to the macro \verb|\MyCommand|:


\verb|\DTLgetvalueforkey{\MyCommand}{value}{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}|\\
\begingroup\footnotesize
\verb|% define the macro "\MyCommand".|\\
\verb|% use the database "definitions".|\\
\verb|% use the column whose name is "value".|\\
\verb|% use the row which in the column "key" holds the item "MyFromData".|
\endgroup

\DTLgetvalueforkey{\MyCommand}{value}{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}        

\verb|\MyCommand| yields: \MyCommand

Now you can use \verb|\MyCommand| within the argument of
\verb|\printdate|.

\verb|\printdate{\MyCommand}| yields: \printdate{\MyCommand}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You wish to have the date formatted as:
  `<name of the month><non-break-space><day>,<space><year>`.

I did not find a way of accomplishing this easily using the **isodate** package.
Therefore I suggest not using the **isodate** package but using the packages **datetime2** and **datetime2-calc** which come from the author who also wrote the **datatool** package, *Dr. Nicola Talbot*.

Using these packages you can easily define new date styles according to your likings:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{datatool, datetime2, datetime2-calc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DTMnewdatestyle{MyDatestyle}{% definitions
  % the \number does remove leading zeros from the "day"-element of the date.
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMmonthname{##2}~\number##3, ##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\begin{filecontents*}{MyDataFile.def}
WhatsoeverKeyA,WhatsoeverValueA
WhatsoeverKeyB,WhatsoeverValueB
MyFromDate,1990-10-09
WhatsoeverKeyC,WhatsoeverValueC
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\data{MyDataFile}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{definitions}{\data.def}

\begin{document}

A new date-style can be defined using \textbf{datetime2 and datetime2-calc}:
\begin{verbatim}
\DTMnewdatestyle{MyDatestyle}{% definitions
  % the \number does remove leading zeros from the "day"-element of the date.
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMmonthname{##2}~\number##3, ##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
\end{verbatim}

\hrulefill

This does both print the return-value and save the return-value to
\verb|\dtlcurrentvalue|:

\verb|\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}{value}|:
\DTLfetch{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}{value}\\
\begingroup\footnotesize
\verb|% use the database "definitions".|\\
\verb|% use the column whose name is "value".|\\
\verb|% use the row which in the column "key" holds the item "MyFromData".|
\endgroup

\verb|\dtlcurrentvalue| yields: \dtlcurrentvalue

Now you can use \verb|\dtlcurrentvalue| within the argument of
\verb|\DTMdate| and \verb|\DTMDate|.
\begin{verbatim}
\begingroup
\DTMsetdatestyle{MyDatestyle}
\DTMdate{\dtlcurrentvalue}

\DTMDate{\dtlcurrentvalue}
\endgroup
\end{verbatim}%
yields:

\begingroup
\DTMsetdatestyle{MyDatestyle}
\DTMdate{\dtlcurrentvalue}

\DTMDate{\dtlcurrentvalue}
\endgroup

\hrulefill

This does just save the return-value to the macro \verb|\MyCommand|:

\verb|\DTLgetvalueforkey{\MyCommand}{value}{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}|\\
\begingroup\footnotesize
\verb|% define the macro "\MyCommand".|\\
\verb|% use the database "definitions".|\\
\verb|% use the column whose name is "value".|\\
\verb|% use the row which in the column "key" holds the item "MyFromData".|
\endgroup

\DTLgetvalueforkey{\MyCommand}{value}{definitions}{key}{MyFromDate}

\verb|\MyCommand| yields: \MyCommand


Now you can use \verb|\MyCommand| within the argument of
\verb|\DTMdate| and \verb|\DTMDate|.
\begin{verbatim}
\begingroup
\DTMsetdatestyle{MyDatestyle}
\DTMdate{\MyCommand}

\DTMDate{\MyCommand}
\endgroup
\end{verbatim}%
yields:

\begingroup
\DTMsetdatestyle{MyDatestyle}
\DTMdate{\MyCommand}

\DTMDate{\MyCommand}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]